# How can i enable debug at front end side without admin access?

Tags: magento-1.9, template-hints

I want to see template path hint at front side using file changes. I don’t want change in admin area for template hint. Any suggestion?

Comment: do you have access to the db?

Comment: Thanks for fast reply. No, i have not access of db @Marius

Comment: do you have access to the code at least? I mean, can you edit files?

Comment: Yes, I have @Marius

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All blocks with templates associated to them should extend `Mage_Core_Block_Template`.
The template path hints are displayed via the method `fetchView` in the class I mentioned.
So you temporarily do this:
edit [this line](https://github.com/OpenMage/magento-mirror/blob/magento-1.9/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php#L221)

```
if ($this->getShowTemplateHints()) {
```

and make it:

```
$storeId = Mage::app()->getStore()->getId();
if ($this->getShowTemplateHints() || $storeId) {
```

This will enable the template path hints for fontend

and [this line](https://github.com/OpenMage/magento-mirror/blob/magento-1.9/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php#L228)

```
if (self::$_showTemplateHintsBlocks) {
```

make it

```
if (self::$_showTemplateHintsBlocks || $storeId) {
```

this will show you the block names in the template path hints.

Don't forget to revert your changes when you are done.

Comment: Can we do it by `xml` file?

Comment: No, you cannot.